# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in a random time after start a task

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a piece of code of my application that's I get the error where I don't have idea what's the problem and this error occurs when I open the device camera and start to get capture frames. The weird thing here is, this works but gets the error below in a short or long time of the capture has started.

> Error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xN)" where "N" is a hypothetical hex memory address.

The code:

```
- (void)imageToBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)source
{ 
  NSData *data;

  CVImageBufferRef buffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(source);
  CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer, 0);

  size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(buffer);
  size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(buffer);
  void *bufferSrc = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(buffer);

  data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bufferSrc length:bytesPerRow * height];
  CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(buffer, 0);

  [self.delegate didReceivedFrame:data];
}

@end


#pragma mark - AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate implementation
@implementation AVCaptureManager (AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate)

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self imageToBuffer:sampleBuffer];
  });
}
```

This error normally occurs in the line:

```
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer, 0);
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the error is here:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self imageToBuffer:sampleBuffer];
});
```

This call is dispatched asynchronously, and to my knowledge `CMSampleBuffer`s don't necessarily hold on to their contents (the data might be released before the sample buffer object).

Make sure you dispatch it **synchronously** on the main queue.

BTW: Why do you dispatch on the main thread in the first place?

Comment: Thanks Erik, is working well. About the run this process in main thread. I'm getting camera frames to pass in network via wifi or bluetooth. Probably I will need to optimize this and I not sure if this will work smooth using only main thread.

Comment: I have the same random crash. I need to get current CMSampleBufferRef and to use it later at any time. Should I use only dispatch_sync in AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate method to make copy of current buffer? Should I use CMSampleBufferCreateCopy for that?